# SOLR Dropping Emoji Miscellaneous characters

Tags: unicode, solr, lucene, emoji

It looks like SOLR is considering what should be valid Unicode characters as invalid, and dropping them.

I "proved" this by turning on query debug to see what the parser was doing with my query. Here's an example:

Query = 'ァ☀' (\u30a1\u2600)

Here's what SOLR did with it:

'debug':{
    'rawquerystring':u'\u30a1\u2600',
    'querystring':u'\u30a1\u2600',
    'parsedquery':u'(+DisjunctionMaxQuery((text:\u30a1)))/no_coord',
    'parsedquery_toString':u'+(text:\u30a1)',

As you can see, was OK with 'ァ', but it ATE the "Black Sun" character.

I haven't tried ALL of the Block, but I've confirmed it also doesn't like ⛿ (\u26ff) and ♖ (\u2656).

I'm using SOLR with Jetty, so the various TomCat issues WRT character encoding shouldn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very likely has more to do with the Analyzer.  I don't see anything specifying the treatment of those sorts of characters exactly, but they are probably being treated very much as punctuation by the [`StandardAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) (or whatever Analyzer you may be using), and so will not be present in the final query.  `StandardAnalyzer` implements the rules set forward in [UAX-29, Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/), in order to separate input into tokens.

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks!

Comment: @femto Please suggest what analyzer should be used here