# String query of unicode (emoji) character in Elastic Search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I have some articles in my ES index that contain emoji icons.  I'd like to perform a search for articles that contain specific emoji characters.  I'm using compose.io as my ES provider and via ElasticHQ I can see the emojis in the data - they are rendered as icons in OS X, so I assume the unicode is stored correctly.  However, when I run this query I get no results.  If I run a plain text search I do get my results.  I'm using mongoosastic.

```
Article.search({query_string: {query: ""}},
            {fields: "title"}, 
            function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error: " + err);
            } else {    
                console.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results));         
            }
        });

//results: {"took":6,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Comment: Potentially related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773786/solr-dropping-emoji-miscellaneous-characters. (Test it out with the Analyze API:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/indices-analyze.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter, I get the following:  

curl -XGET -u dev-user:pass123 'https://foo.com:10724/_analyze?analyzer=standard' -d 'foo'
{"tokens":[{"token":"foo","start_offset":0,"end_offset":3,"type":"<ALPHANUM>","position":1}]}

curl -XGET -u dev-user:pass123 'https://foo.com:10724/_analyze?analyzer=standard' -d ''
{"tokens":[]}

It means very little to me.  I’m assuming I need to install some sort of Analyzer that can handle unicode?

Comment: It sounds like (from the Solr post) that the Lucene standard analyzer may not interpret the emoji range as valid Unicode characters (and strips them out).

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I've had a few conversations over at the elastic.co forum and yes, the standard analyzer can't do this sort of thing.  What I've done for now (pending writing my own analyzer) is to encode the emojis into strings and index these instead.

Comment: Cool.  Was going to suggest that for a quick fix! (make sure to use a new field for your encodings so you can boost them separately.)  If you end up going the route of patching Lucene, please think about contributing the patch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it looks like ElasticSearch also cannot directly enables searching emoticons. Also, I tried using corresponding unicode value, and that also doesn't seems to work. May be converting raw unicode value to a string would help.